# Abrir e fechar várias abas no navegador com Python

Tags: javascript, python, navegador-de-internet, selenium-webdriver

Olá preciso de uma ajuda. Preciso que esse script que eu tenho (Python e JS) abra um determinado numero de abas e depois de um intervalo de tempo feche e reabra as mesmas abas novamente. Porém para não fechar o navegador ainda preciso que sempre uma delas fique aberta. Por hora eu estou nesse codigo porém faz dois dias que eu não saio dele. Obs: Estou utilizando Selenium!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import json
import sys
import os
import pyautogui

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

arquivoConf = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sys.argv[1])

with open(arquivoConf) as json_data_file:
    config = json.load(json_data_file)

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(config['from_nameFirefox'])
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)

num_of_tabs = 10
time.sleep(10)
while True:
    t = len(browser.window_handles)
    print (t) 
    for i in range(1,  t):
        browser.window_handles[i]
        time.sleep(2)
        print ( 'Fechando tab ' + str(i) )
        for x in range(1, num_of_tabs):
        browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
        browser.execute_script('window.open("","_self").close()')
        browser.execute_script('window.close()')
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
while True:

    num_current_tabs = len(browser.window_handles)

    # Fechar todas - 1 abas, deixando uma aberta para não fechar o navegador.
    for i in range(1, num_current_tabs):
        browser.window_handles[i]
        browser.close()
        time.sleep(2)

    # Script para abrir as páginas.
    for total_new_tabs in range(1, num_of_tabs):
        self.browser.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")

        # Foca na última aba aberta
        browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1]) 
        time.sleep(2)

    # Fecha a aba remanescente das anteriormente fechadas.
    browser.windows_handles[0].close()
```

Comment: Agradeço amigo a atenção porém esse seu código ainda não esta fazendo o que eu quero. Na verdade acho que foi um erro meu pois preciso que ele abra varias guias ou tabs na mesma janela do navegador. Não em varias janelas como foi mostrado. Estou utilizando esse código no momento (https://pastebin.com/XRHgmprS) , se puder ajudar agradeço muito!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os atalhos do teclado para criar abas e fechar. Por exemplo: 
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> para abrir uma nova aba e <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> para fechar.

Para fazer isso no selenium, basta:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

# Abre uma nova aba
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't') 

# Carrega a nova aba
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

# Fecha a aba
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w') 


driver.close()
```