# Fazer com que ele abra e reabra a cada x tempo um numero de tabs Python e Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Preciso com que esse meu código a cada uma hora faça o processo de reabrir todas as abas ou configurar ou apenas fechar tudo e executar esse código a cada uma hora. Tem como?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json
import sys
import os
import pyautogui

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print ("Como usar:\n\t" + sys.argv[0] + " config.txt")
    sys.exit()

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

arquivoConf = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sys.argv[1])

with open(arquivoConf) as json_data_file:
    config = json.load(json_data_file)

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(config['from_nameFirefox'])
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile)

def fazerLogin():
    browser.get('about:preferences')
    browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("linkTargeting").click();')

    browser.get(config['url'])
    user     = browser.find_element_by_name('j_username')
    password = browser.find_element_by_name('j_password')
    user.send_keys(config['user'])
    password.send_keys(config['pass'])
    browser.find_element_by_id('submitButton').click();

    time.sleep(10)

def desceQnt(valor):
    #print ( '--->'  + str(valor))
    for i in range(0, valor):
    #print ( '->'  + str(1))
        pyautogui.press('down')
        time.sleep(2)

    pyautogui.press('enter')

def passarEntreTabs():  
    # Volta para primeiro Dashboard
    pyautogui.click(config['posicaoElemento'][0], config['posicaoElemento'][1])
    pyautogui.press('home')
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('enter')

    for i in range(1, config['countDashboard']):
        browser.execute_script('window.open("' +  config['url'] + ' ", "_blank");')
        time.sleep(config['carregar_tela'])

        pyautogui.moveTo(config['posicaoElemento'][0], config['posicaoElemento'][1], duration= 2)
        pyautogui.click(config['posicaoElemento'][0], config['posicaoElemento'][1])
        time.sleep(3)
        pyautogui.press('home')

        desceQnt(i)

        time.sleep(3)


        print ( 'Fechando Ultima Aba' ) 
        browser.window_handles[0]
        browser.execute_script('window.open("","_self").close()')

        os.system('cls')    
        print ( 'Setup configurado ')
        print ( time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") )
        print ( 'Entrando no While TRUE')

#def fecharPorra():

fazerLogin()
passarEntreTabs()

while True:
    numberOfTabs = len(browser.window_handles)

    for i in range(0, numberOfTabs):
        browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[i])

        if ( browser.current_url == config['url'] ):
            browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1].click();window.frames[0].loadDashboardLayout();')

        else:
            browser.execute_script('location.reload();')

        time.sleep(config['tempo_Refrash'])
```

Comment: Qual a diferença para [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259769/5878)?

Comment: Estou usando outro script e a logica. Além disso coloco essa possibilidade em aberto "configurar ou apenas fechar tudo e executar esse código a cada uma hora".